# How can I change the log level on the fly with tracing?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

As a developer I would like to adjust the log level on the fly. For example, I don't want to log `debug!` events when everything is going fine, but when something happens, I would like to adjust the log level without restarting the application to change the log level. I check the documentation and can't find an example there, so I want to know if it is possible to do that.

```rust
// how can I change the max_level of subscriber after it was initialised?
let subscriber = tracing_subscriber::fmt().with_max_level(Level::INFO).finish();
tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber);

debug!("some log message");
```

Comment: I think you can use https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/filter/fn.filter_fn.html with a global variable you can have a dynamic global level filter

Comment: @Stargateur this api looks promising. thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [reload handler](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/reload/index.html) exactly for this. Save remote handler in some global state and call it to change log level. See example under "Reloading a Filtered layer"

Comment: I can't figure out types of reloadable layer and the handle to store in an Arc/Mut ! :sigh:

Answer (score -9):

Use log4rs instead. It reads configs from a file which you can change on the fly.
I use it in one of my projects, it works like a charm.